# ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response when trying to scrape Reddit data with PRAW - How do I authenticate?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, reddit

I am trying to scrape some reddit data from the application I created, I later want to input them into a dataframe pr CSV file. I keep receiving the following error:

```
ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response
```

My code is pretty standard:

```
import praw
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='', client_secret='', user_agent='', password='', username='',)
    # get 10 hot posts from the MachineLearning subreddit
    hot_posts = reddit.subreddit('MachineLearning').hot(limit=10)
    for post in hot_posts:
        print(post.title)
```

Other solutions about this error keep saying you have to authenticate yourself. But what does this mean? The reddit solutions on https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#application-only-oauth are still pretty confusing.

Comment: Have you filled up the required fields properly? `client_id='', client_secret='', user_agent='', password='', username='',`  ?

Comment: Yes I have, I just removed them from the post for security reasons.

Comment: if anything goes wrong, it should be these variables, that's why `authentication error`, check if you put them properly (all credentials should be valid)